# How to input data with more than one text box in a form with JavaScript and get it displayed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a simple code that such accepts data input into two text boxes (firstname and lastname) ad upon the user clicking a submit button the input data should get displayed on the screen. But I only get the first input data displayed. Why?

Here is my code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Forms With JavaScript</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<H1>Forms With JavaScript</H1>

<FORM name=myForm>
Enter your firstname: <INPUT TYPE="text" name="theFirstname"><BR><BR>
Enter your lastname: <INPUT TYPE="text" name="theLastname"><BR><BR>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Process" onclick="PrintFullName()">
</FORM>



<SCRIPT type="text/JavaScript">


function PrintFullName()
{   
    var fname = document.myForm.theFirstname;
    document.write(fname.value);

    var sname = document.myForm.theLastname;
    document.write(sname.value);
}

</SCRIPT>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you call `document.write()`, `sname` becomes undefined and throws an error. You can get around it by changing the function to the following:

```
function PrintFullName()
{   
    var fname = document.myForm.theFirstname;    
    var sname = document.myForm.theLastname;
    document.write(fname.value + " " + sname.value);
}
```

Comment: Hi Psychemaster. I did the change as you suggested but now nothing gets displayed when I click the submit button.

Comment: Can't imagine why that would be, I used your code verbatim with my changed function and it worked perfectly fine...

Comment: Thank you Psychemaster, it worked now. One more thing though, I noticed that the output is sent to another page. Could you tell me why does that happen?